# Efficient way to split a string into an array - PHP

Tags: php, split, delimited

What is the best way to split the below `$string` to get the array `$cars` in PHP?

```
$string = '{xa}{y}{z12}{123}{2}{aabb}';

$cars = array("{xa}","{y}","{z12}", "{123}", "{2}", "{aabb}");
```

I need each array element with brackets eg : `{xa}`

Comment: Maybe something like `preg_match_all("/\{.\}/", $string, $x);`.

Comment: [preg_split()](http://php.net/preg_split)? since your delimiters aren't the same throughout, you can't really use `explode()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$string = str_replace("}{","},{",$string);
$x = explode(',',$string);
```

Comment: I need each array element with brackets eg : {xa}

Comment: @MDeSilva This will preserve brackets.

Comment: Isn't that good to use preg_split() to do the job ? which one is the best ?

Comment: @MDeSilva Regex is usually slower than doing linear operations like string replacement.